# How to read Android's 'Use network provided time zone' setting from Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In android date and time settings there are two fields that I need to know the values of in my Flutter application:

1) Automatic date & time - use network provided time

2) Automatic time zone - use network provided time zone
[image]

How can I get access to the current value of these settings in my Flutter application?

I'm struggling to google this as the keywords 'settings' and 'time' are giving many irrelevant results.